# remove leading whitespace from xsl while calling x:transform

Tags: xml, jsp, xslt

Hi I am trying to perform an xml-xsl transform from jsp using following code:

```
<c:import url="/global/xsl/sub-nav.xsl" var="xslt"/>
<c:import url="/sitemap.xml" var="xmltext"/>
<x:transform xml="${xmltext}" xslt="${xslt}">
   <x:param name="relativeURL" value="/personal/accounts/"/>
   <x:param name="fullRelativeURL" value="/personal/accounts/sba/"/>
</x:transform>
```

The problem here is that, I cannot make any change in xsl file. It has a leading space before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` i.e. the very first line of xsl. Is there a way i can omit that space while calling transform from jsp? Otherwise it gives a 500 error if I dont get rid of that leading space.

Comment: Show us the stack-trace from the server.

Answer (score 0):

A strict reading of the [XML spec (production 22 "prolog")](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-prolog) says that there cannot be whitespace before the XML prolog. Therefore the XSL file with leading whitespace is broken and ***must*** be fixed.

I suppose you could write code to load the XSL file into memory while removing the leading spaces, then pass the corrected buffer to the transform instead of the original XSL... but that seems like a lot of work, and would happen each time the JSP was invoked.

Comment: what do u suggest sir? U just explained my problem.

Comment: Did you read the second paragraph of my answer?  If you can't change the XSL, then you have to fix it and either cache a copy for reuse or re-fix it every time.  There's no way to tell the XSL processor to accept invalid XML.

Answer (score 0):

You realize that the value of `${xslt}` is a string, right? ;)